# Plotting a function with one parameter (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, parameters, anonymous-function

I would like to plot an function fx(y) = 3*y-y.^(3)-x with x being a parameter. I would like to graph fx(y) versus y for x varying over `0:0.5:6` all in one graph. For some reason it only works when you give x a single value and then use a anonymous function, but this is not what I need.

```
x=@(y) 3.*y-y.^(3)-x;
ezplot(fx)
```

This gives me 3y-y^(3)-x = 0, but this is not what I need. I need to have a graph of fx versus y for the parameter x changing from 0 to 6 in steps of 0.5. This would give me `length(x)` number of graphs in one plot.

Comment: This is a programming site. Please edit your question to show the code that you're using.

Comment: Is `y` dependent on `x`? If not, what do you want `y` to be? If it is, can you rewrite the equations?

Comment: y is independent of x, x is just a parameter. I would like y to vary from [-3,3].So y is on the horizontal axis and fx(y) is on the vertical axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
y = -3:0.01:3;
x = 0:0.5:6;

n1 = numel(y);
n2 = numel(x);

fx = repmat(3.*y-y.^(3),n2,1)-repmat(x',1,n1);
plot(y,fx)
```

[image]