# Plotting a Parametric Equation

Tags: matlab, function, plot

I would like to plot the following curve: `Ca(t) = (a + cos(t) , -2a^(2) + sin(t))`
The goal is to plot a number of curves for `a = -2:0.1:2`.

```
clf
a=zeros(1,41);
for i=1:41
    a(i)=-2+(i-1)/10;
    x=linspace(0,2*pi);
    plot([a(i)+cos(x) -2*a(i)^2+sin(x)])
    hold on
    grid on
end
```

This code doesn't seem to do the job. Can anyone help me? Or simplify my code. I know I could use the syms option, but how can I get a plot for all those different values of a.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plotting a function with one parameter (MATLAB)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172326/plotting-a-function-with-one-parameter-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

That was actually a neat figure!

```
a = (-2:0.1:2)';
t = linspace(0,2*pi,100);

n1 = numel(a);
n2 = numel(t);

Ca1 = repmat(a,1,n2) + repmat(cos(t),n1,1)
Ca2 = repmat(-2*a.^(2),1,n2) + repmat(sin(t),n1,1),

plot(Ca1,Ca2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
syms t
a=-2:0.1:2;
x=1:length(a);
y=1:length(a);
for i=1:length(a)
    x=a(i)+cos(t);
    y=-2*a(i)^(2)+sin(t);
    hold on
    ezplot(x,y)
end
```